# How to change the style of documentation which appears on hover in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I recently migrated from Visual Studio 2013 to 2015. It was a visually satisfactory transition. But suddenly one of my favorite feature disappeared.

Before:
[image: before]

And after:
[image: after]

It is not colorful anymore. I played around with text editor options, fonts and styles, but couldn't figure it out. Does anyone know how to bring it back?

Comment: IIRC, this feature was provided by Visual Studio Power Tools in 2013, but was integrated into Visual Studio 2015 directly.  Did you/do you have power tools installed?

Comment: @BJMyers I checked. It is installed in my VS 2015.

Comment: You don't need to install power tools in VS2015.

Comment: @vendettamit I meant VS 2015 already has power tools in options.